# Change input value onclick button - pure javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, input, onclick

I have two buttons and if I click on some button I need to change value in input text and change total price (product price * value of button - 2 or 4 Qty).

I know that it's simple but I'm not good in javascript or jQuery. Answer in jsfiddle would be best.
My jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/J7m7m/1/

My simple code:

```
Product price: $500
<br>
Total price: $500
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="change()" value="2&#x00A;Qty">
<input type="button" value="4&#x00A;Qty">
<br>
Total <input type="text" id="count" value="1">
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Another simple solution for this case using jQuery. Keep in mind it's not a good practice to use inline javascript.

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mtashev/J7m7m/12/)

I've added IDs to html on the total price and on the buttons.
Here is the jQuery.

```
$('#two').click(function(){
    $('#count').val('2');
    $('#total').text('Product price: $1000');
});

$('#four').click(function(){
    $('#count').val('4');
    $('#total').text('Product price: $2000');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Try This(Simple javascript):-

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <script>
          function change(value){
          document.getElementById("count").value= 500*value;
          document.getElementById("totalValue").innerHTML= "Total price: $" + 500*value;
          }
          
       </script>
       <body>
          Product price: $500
          <br>
          <div id= "totalValue">Total price: $500 </div>
          <br>
          <input type="button" onclick="change(2)" value="2&#x00A;Qty">
          <input type="button" onclick="change(4)" value="4&#x00A;Qty">
          <br>
          Total <input type="text" id="count" value="1">
       </body>
    </html>
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: I would suggest not to do it like this, because developers need to learn to separate their JavaScript from their html.  Obtrusive JavaScript isn't good.

Answer (score 2):

using html5 data attribute...

try this

**Html**

```
Product price: $<span id="product_price">500</span>

<br>Total price: $500
<br>
<input type="button" data-quantity="2" value="2&#x00A;Qty">
<input type="button" data-quantity="4" class="mnozstvi_sleva" value="4&#x00A;Qty">
<br>Total
<input type="text" id="count" value="1">
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
$('input:button').click(function () {
  $('#count').val($(this).data('quantity') * $('#product_price').text());
});
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/J7m7m/5/)

Answer (score 2):

And here is the non jQuery answer.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J7m7m/7/

```
function changeText(value) {
     document.getElementById('count').value = 500 * value;   
}
```

HTML slight modification:

```
Product price: $500
<br>
Total price: $500
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="changeText(2)" value="2&#x00A;Qty">
<input type="button" class="mnozstvi_sleva" value="4&#x00A;Qty" onClick="changeText(4)">
<br>
Total <input type="text" id="count" value="1"/>
```

EDIT: It is very clear that this is a non-desired way as pointed out below (I had it coming). So in essence, this is how you would do it in plain old javascript. Most people would suggest you to use jQuery (other answer has the jQuery version) for good reason.

Comment: As I mentioned to @Vikash Pandey, it isn't best practice to have obtrusive JavaScript (`onclick="changeText(2)"`) within your html.

Answer (score 0):

## This will work fine for you

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function myfun(){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#select").click(
        function(){
        var data=$("#select").val();
            $("#disp").val(data);
                            });
    });
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>id <input type="text" name="user" id="disp"></p>
    <select id="select" onclick="myfun()">
    <option name="1"value="one">1</option>
    <option name="2"value="two">2</option>
    <option name="3"value="three"></option>
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: oops..!!..sorry i have just joined stackoverflow..and not seen posted date.

Answer (score -1):

My Attempt ( [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8m7x/2/))

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#buttons input[type=button]').on('click', function () {
        var qty = $(this).data('quantity');
        var price = $('#totalPrice').text(); 
        $('#count').val(price * qty);
    });
});
```

Html

```
  Product price:$500
<br>Total price: $<span id='totalPrice'>500</span>
<br>
<div id='buttons'>
    <input id='qty2' type="button" data-quantity='2' value="2&#x00A;Qty">
    <input id='qty2' type="button" class="mnozstvi_sleva" data-quantity='4' value="4&#x00A;Qty">
</div>
<br>Total
<input type="text" id="count" value="1">
```