# Append button's value to input text , every time button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input

Let me show you a piece of my code so you know what I'm struggling with.

```
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

This is the input element I am talking about. What I want to do is put the value of :

```
<input type="button" id="b1" value="1" />
```

in the textbox everytime the button is clicked.

A side question I can't google because it's part of searching syntax.

What is the difference between `""` and `''` (with something in-between) and when do you use one of them?

EDIT: Right now the click event is adding the value of the button to the textbox. But not to the text inside the textbox! IT just literally adds it, as if the textbox is a division or something.

The jquery/javascript code

```
$("#b1").click(toev);

function toev(){           
               $("#input").text($(append($(this).val())));
                };
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.?

Comment: I think that something went wrong with your formatting. Try using the "{}" icon in the editor to show something as code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals

Comment: You can use javascript to add value to the inputbox

Comment: Are you looking for `document.getElementById("input").value += document.getElementById("b1").value`?

Comment: @Katana314 What do you mean? It looks normal to me.


@ Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

 $("#b1").click(toev);


            function toev(){
               $("#input").append(this.val());
                };

Comment: @Zeretil That's because someone edited your question for you. It used to look like this: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20614814/1 Your HTML wasn't formatted as a code block (by offsetting it with 4 spaces).

Comment: This question seems to be very similar to yours.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740713/change-input-value-onclick-button-pure-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @Ted It is, but I need it to work with 'this'. So it's not quite helping, since it's still not working :s 

apsillers Yeah I noticed. Thanks Jason P!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this :[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mE6CX/)

```
$('#b1').click(
    function(){
        $('#input').val($('#input').val()+$(this).val());
    }
);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thank you! I would upvote you if I had the reputation.

Comment: This doesn't really assigns the value in DOM. See my Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

How are you currently trying at set the `value` attribute to `1` upon button click?

There is no difference between `''` and `""` other than you can use single quotes inside of double quotes without having to escape the characters, and vise versa:

`"I like to eat 'cheese'."` vs `"I like to eat \"cheese\"."`

`'Do you like to eat "cheese"?'` vs `'Do you like to eat \'cheese\'?'`

Which ever one you decide to use depends on code style or whether it makes your coding easier.  As [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20615020/1034372) pointed out, this might not always be the case across all languages.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. And no I am not, I want the value of the button to be added to the text inside the textbox everytime it is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Use plain javascript for this simple task. Get button id, then add its value to input. Example:

```
document.getElementById('b1').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('input').value += this.value;
};
```

And if you want to clear all contents of textbox and then add value:

```
document.getElementById('b1').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('input').value = this.value;
};
```

Comment: I like this answer, since the original poster hasn't stated if he's using jQuery or not.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you want to do is

-Have a textbox (I'm assuming not read only)

-Have a button with an event handler

-On the "Click" of a button change the value in the text box.

via jQuery

```
//button handler
$('#b1').click(function () {
   $('#input').val(1)
});
```

Breakdown of what is happening:

```
$('#b1')                 //jQuery selector to select the button element by it's ID
.click(function () { }); //the function to be called when you click the button
$('#input')              //jQuery selector to select the input (textbox) element
.val(1)                  //Set the input (textbox) value to 1
```

For your second question "" vs ''.  In javascript there is no real difference and they can be used interchangably, and inside each other "''" or '""' which will often come up.  In different languages this might not be the case, Ex C# "" == string, where '' == char, etc.

Comment: Value of a button could be dynamic added by ajax or php or else, threfore hardcoding a value shouldn't be a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

well, what i could understand from your question, you want to put value insise textbox. you can do the fowwling.

its better that you provide `ID` or `class` to `input type="text"` or else this would put values inside all textbox available on page

```
 $('#b1').click(function() {
        $('#input').val("whatever value you want");
    });
```

if you want button value to go inside textbox, you can do following..

```
$('#b1').click(function() {
     var btnValue = $(this).val();            
    $('#input').val(btnValue );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This assigns the value also in DOM, therefore you can create a button to delete the value if you like or mistyped.

```
$('#b1').click(
    function(){
            var inputValue  = $('#input').val();
            var input       = $('#input');
            var buttonValue = $(this).val();
            var newInputValue = inputValue + buttonValue;
            input.attr('value',newInputValue );
    }
);
```