# Input type=number along wih label

Tags: html, forms

I am using an input type="number" for incrementing numbers, however I do not want this input field to be visible for a few reasons (not important). Therefore, I was hoping to use labels for interacting with the element.

Currently, for example: `<input type="number" step="1" value="1" min="1"/>`

I want to use a label, one for increasing the value and another to decrease, unfortunately using the code for labels, `<label for="example1">` only seems to select the number/box of the number.

Does anyone know of a method for having a label increase the value, or decrease the value?

Comment: You'll probably need JavaScript for this. HTML alone won't do.

Comment: There is nothing about `<label>` elements that does anything more besides switch focus to the associated input element. You will need client-scripting if you want to manipulate the input without displaying the actual input element on-screen.

Comment: This is kind of incorrect, as if I were to have an input type checkbox, the label would tick and untick a checkbox, I hoped something would exist to do a similar function for this.

Comment: are you comfortable using jQuery or do you want to go html only?

Comment: Should only one selection be valid? Then maybe <radio name="selection" id="val1" value="1"><label for="val1">1</label> ... would be an option

Comment: I would rather it be a HTML pure method, mainly because I'm exploring the uses that pure HTML can have to demonstrate purpose.

Comment: why would you use a label for this when html provides you with a button? Want the button to look like a label? Use CSS.

Comment: dsuess, I am intending to have many elements on the page, which are hidden/shown depending on the input. Therefore for this specific use, I would need to do two inputs per element, therefore I would like an increment method.

Comment: HTML is a _markup language_. You may get some user interface components by web browser, e.g. range-sliders or calendars, but no further control. JavaScript is the technology to make websites dynamic. (The 3rd one, CSS, is for styling this HTML-elements). See also ["W3School: JavaScript is one of the 3 languages all web developers must learn"](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to make this work without some javascript in their. [Here'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740713/change-input-value-onclick-button-pure-javascript-or-jquery)s a nice SO post that has a bunch of options for you or if you don't mind a little jquery you can give this a shot:

```
<input id="thing" type="number" value="1" />
<label id="stuff" for="thing" >Hey!</label>
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#stuff').click(function () {
        whatitis = parseInt(document.getElementById('thing').value);
        $('#thing').val(whatitis + 1);
    })
})
```