# retreive html data into form input using submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have created a form for payment and retrieved data from database to the input fields. my html is below:

```html
<table>
 <form name="postForm" action="form_process.php" method="POST" >
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid=time().rand(1000,99999); ?>" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>amount</td><td><input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" /></td></tr>



 <tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $user_name; ?>" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>phone</td><td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $user_mobile; ?>" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>productinfo</td><td><input type="text" name="productinfo" value="" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="surl" value="success.php" size="64" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="furl" value="fail.php" size="64" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="submit" /></td><td><input type="reset" /></td></tr>
 </form>
</table>
```

i have the following design for my website for customers to choose plans. when the user clicks the paynow button, they are redirected to this form. 
[image]

when the use clicks the button,the corresponding amount should be added to the input field automatically. if its 400 the input should be 400 or 300 if 300. how can i do this inside submit button?

Comment: which input field needs the value ?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740713/change-input-value-onclick-button-pure-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: @melvin amount field

Comment: where is the amount field in code ?

Comment: 3rd line. at the top

Comment: So you need the id(already in the amount filed) and the price ?

Comment: yes...........................

Comment: You are creating invalid HTML; you can not nest `form` between `table` and `tr` … fix this first of all.

Comment: @CBroe okey. i will

Comment: Do you want this to only fill a form field (so that the user will be able to see the value there, while they stay on the same page), or do you want to submit the form using that chosen price? For the former, you will need JavaScript; for the latter, you could simply switch to using `button` elements (instead of input type=submit), those allow you to specify a submit value different from the button description …

Comment: the form is in another page. the choosen price should apear in the amount field

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Submit You can give input type as Button like plan1,plan2,plan3 and create onClick function for each button for example

```
<button onclick="plan1()">Plan1</button>

<p id="plan1">Plan1 contents</p>

<script>
function plan1() {
  document.getElementById("plan1").innerHTML = "Document Data";
}
```

like wise

Answer (score 0):

So you need to perform an click function on button. Your 3 buttons may have a data attribute price mentioning the value like

```
<input type="button" data-price="300">
```

By acessing the data attribute you fill the input field.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('input[name="amount"]').val($(this).data(price));
});
```

Comment: where should i add this

Comment: In your js file.

Comment: let me check and tell

Comment: I don't see jQuery in his tag list?!

Comment: so ? He don't know to do it So he asked for help. Also there is a tag `javascript` .I don't know whether it is possible without js @RezaSaadati

Comment: both my pages are separate. the button is in one page and the form in another. the problem now is how can i redirect when the user clicks button

Comment: Vanilla JS, yes but jQuery is not needed for this simple code.

Comment: @RezaSaadati can you please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following class to your 3 sections:
   `class="month"`
2. Give that input field an ID where you want the result to be outputed: e.g: `<input type="text" name="productinfo" id="productinfo">`
3. Add following script in your JavaScript file: 
   `const month = document.querySelectorAll('.month');
   const productInfo = document.getElementById('productinfo');
   month.forEach((m) => m.addEventListener('click', (e) => productInfo.value = m.getAttribute('data-month')));`

`data-month` contrains the value. In this case 100, 200, 300.

```js
const month = document.querySelectorAll('.month');
const productInfo = document.getElementById('productinfo');

month.forEach((m) => m.addEventListener('click', (e) => productInfo.value = m.getAttribute('data-month')));
```

```html
<input class="month" type="button" value="PLAY NOW" data-month="100">
<input class="month" type="button" value="PLAY NOW" data-month="200">
<input class="month" type="button" value="PLAY NOW" data-month="300">

<input type="text" id="productinfo">
```

Comment: where should i give the id=month

Comment: @kingkhan sorry, my bad. It's not an ID. It should be a class. So add to all your buttons: `class="month"`.

Comment: i have done as you said but the value is not aded to the box

Comment: @kingkhan did you add the ID `productinfo` to the input text field, which should receive the value?

Comment: @kingkhan where is your JavaScript loaded? In `<head>` or in footer? If not in footer, please place it in the footer. Also please tell me the error of your console.