# How can i add value to input with a button?

Tags: javascript

i'm making a web 'Game' to learn JavaScript, but i got stuck at this. I'm trying to add value to input field. What i'm saying is that if the input field value is when i press button it add's +1 and Value becomes 1. And also i would like to add a limit to it. I can't find anything on documentation or on the web to help me.

```
            <div class="shop">
                <button class="sell">-1</button>
                <input class="number" type="number" value="0">
                <button class="buy"onclick="add">+1</button>
            </div>
```

That's html.
I'm hoping you guys will help me or point me to the right direction to learn it myself.
SORRY FOR BAD ENGLISH

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change input value onclick button - pure javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740713/change-input-value-onclick-button-pure-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var el=document.querySelector(".number")
function add(num){
   el.value=parseInt(el.value)+num
}
```

```html
<div class="shop">
    <button class="sell"onclick="add(-1)">-1</button>
    <input class="number" type="number" value="0">
    <button class="buy"onclick="add(+1)">+1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

its dom manipulation, if you want to learn it here is a tutorial on basic manipulation: https://www.sitepoint.com/dom-manipulation-vanilla-javascript-no-jquery/